# How to change field data from one format to another format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In my form I have four fields. All fields are free to accept numbers and those numbers are converted into predefined character format (I implemented it half with bad logic  but in result field it's not combining all field data into some format. Suppose if you type number 2 in every field then result field should look like : 'XXYYZZNN') ,

What I want is :

1. I will fix a character for each field, for T1 it's  ' X ' ,for T2 it's  ' Y ', 
   for T3 it's  ' Z ' for T4 it's  ' N '
2. Now

if i enter 2 (it can be 0-9) in T1 the result field should show 'XX'

if i enter 3 in T2 the Result field should show 'XXYYY' (hear XX is previous field data)

if i enter 1 in T3 the Result field should show 'XXYYYZ' and

if i enter 4 in T4 the Result field should show 'XXYYYZNNNN'

like wise final result will be 'XXYYYZNNNN'

How can i do this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please see this http://jsfiddle.net/jyotidutta08/s8A5M/

Comment: @JyotiDutta are you looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/s8A5M/1/

Comment: @ Optimus Prime  ya it's showing write result but can i have good logic with less code, i done the same using core java (i used array, for loop and append the result using StringBuffer) but i don't know how to do using jquery

Comment: kaha se ho bhailog...........@ Optimus Prime,

Comment: @JyotiDutta profile pe dekh lena..

Comment: Seems like koala's answer was adding more "X"'s than you wanted, and you may also use for loop in jquery to append the result as in java, see here.http://jsfiddle.net/s8A5M/5/

Comment: @JyotiDutta check my answer http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/s8A5M/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my approach:

Use data attributes to define the character for each input (also use proper label tags and type attributes for inputs)

```
<div>
    <label for="textBox1">T1 :</label>
    <input type="text" id="textBox1" data-char="X"></input>
    <br/>
    <label for="textBox2">T2 :</label>
    <input type="text" id="textBox2" data-char="Y"></input>
    <br/>
    <label for="textBox3">T3 :</label>
    <input type="text" id="textBox2" data-char="Z"></input>
    <br/>
    <label for="textBox4">T4 :</label>
    <input type="text" id="textBox3" data-char="N"></input>
    <br/>
    <label for="message">Result :</label>
    <input type="text" id="message"></input>
</div>
```

Then I would go through all textboxes on every keyup event, parsing their value into a number and appending the corresponding character to the result

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^="textBox"]').keyup(function(){
        var result = '';
        $('[id^="textBox"]').each(function(){
            var count = parseInt($(this).val(),10) || 0;
            result += Array(count+1).join($(this).data('char')); 
        });
        $('#message').val(result);
    });
});
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8A5M/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/s8A5M/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function another_format(len,char_code){
        var ret='';
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
            ret +=char_code;
        }
        return $.trim(ret);
    }
    $("#textBox,#textBox1,#textBox2,#textBox3").keyup(function (event) {
        console.log(event.keyCode);
        if (event.keyCode >=49  && event.keyCode <= 57 && event.keyCode == 8 && event.keyCode=46) {
            var x = another_format($('#textBox').val(),'X');
            var y = another_format($('#textBox1').val(),'Y');
            var z = another_format($('#textBox2').val(),'Z');
            var n = another_format($('#textBox3').val(),'N');
            $('#message').val(x+y+z+n);
        }
    });
});
```